# Woocommerce pages gives 404 error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-404, permalinks

As the title says woocommerce pages give me a 404 error its with all the pages also products and categories. Here you can find the shop: http://dalailauma.nl/ i think its a problem in my permalinks but im not sure. Can someone please help me.

Screenshot of permalinks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Ngq.jpg

Sorry for the dutch language in the screenshots

TIA

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand the question properly (I can see no 404 when I visit the page), but [this script](https://gist.github.com/soulseekah/2321074) helped me a lot while debugging my 404's. Just **make sure you don't run it on a production site**, because it shows a lot of info on top of every page. If you net understand the report, you can post it here and someone might be able to help you better.

Comment: @Juraj.Lorinc I know its because i changed the permalinks to standard again but now i have the very ugly URL

Comment: I would still suggest to install local copy of the site (which you probably already have) and use this script to find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: This is just a guess, but shouldn't it be `/%product%/` instead of `/product` ?